# Include json file in CakePHP 3

Tags: json, cakephp

I have a CahePHP 3 project, in one of my javascript I need to load a json file.
I don't know how to load the json file in my project (I use Netbeans).

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

please read cookbook before any thing

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html